# Why magento run orders email in Cronjob? Any issue if i switch to instant send?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Can anyone please explain why Magento runs order email in **cronjob**?
I set up **cronjob** to send email every 5 minutes.
Is there any issue if I switch to instant sending the customer an instant email confirmation?

My customer asks why he can't receive the order confirmation instantly.

Comment: Improved phrasing; fixed grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain why Magento runs order email in cronjob?

Well [their changelogs](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/Resources/archive/magento_community_edition_user_guide_v1.9.1.pdf#page=828&zoom=auto,-109,342) don't really explain why, but generally the reasons for moving processes to a cron job are:

- It goes from synchronous to asynchronous
- The processing time doesn't matter as much
- The web server doesn't need to handle it (timeouts may not be relevant, memory limits may be larger, interference with the web server pool may be lessened)

> I set up cronjob to send email every 5 minutes. Is there any issue if I switch to instant sending the customer an instant email confirmation?

Not really, no. Other than that it would be a regression in Magento capability. If you take the checkout process for example, when you place your order there is a variety of things that happen; save quote, convert quote to order, prepare payment, capture payment, create invoice, save everything, etc... In this case they've taken the time it takes to generate and send the order email out of this process to improve the checkout speed.

Yes - you can put it back to being sent instantly if you'd like, but my suggestion to you would just be to run your cron every minute instead of every five minutes.

Generally you should employ a rule of "try not to touch core Magento functionality unless you have to.". Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Robbie, IF i change to 1 minutes once. Server load will increase?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be noticeable